# Django REST Framework : serializer fields are missing in the response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `Django 2.0` and `Django REST Framework`.

I have two models `contact` and `transaction` as below

**contact model**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

**amount given model**

```
class AmountGiven(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    amount = models.FloatField(help_text='Amount given to the contact')
    interest_rate = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=None, null=True, help_text='% of interest to be calculated')
    _given_date = models.DateTimeField(
        db_column='given_date',
        default=timezone.now,
        help_text='Date and time when amount was given to the contact'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.amount)

    @property
    def given_date(self):
        return self._given_date

    @given_date.setter
    def given_date(self, value):
        self._given_date = value

    @property
    def interest_to_pay(self):
        if self.interest_rate:    
            datetime_diff = datetime.now(get_localzone()) - self.given_date
            days = datetime_diff.days
            duration_in_year = days/365

            simple_interest_amount = (self.amount * duration_in_year * self.interest_rate)/100

            return simple_interest_amount

        return 0

    @property
    def total_payable(self):
        return self.amount + self.interest_to_pay

    @property
    def amount_due(self):
        returned_amount = 0
        for returned in self.amountreturned_set.all():
            returned_amount += returned.amount

        return self.total_payable - returned_amount
```

and **ContactSerializer**

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='contacts:detail',
        read_only=True
    )

    user = serializers.CurrentUserDefault()

    amount_due = ReadOnlyField(source='amountgiven__amount_due')

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'full_name', 'amount_due')
```

and in **views.py**

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, AdminAuthenticationPermission,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Contact.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

**But there is no field as `amount_due` and `url` in the response returned while making the request to `/contacts/` endpoint with `GET` method.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modeling doesn't allow you to access amount_due in the way  which you'd like.

Your `Contact` model does not have `amountgiven` attribute.
It does however have  `amountgiven_set`  which you can use to obtain a queryset of amountgiven for given contact.

But there can be multiple ones so you need to decide which `amount_due` you want to display in your serializer.

You can use `SerializerMethodField` to serializer the value of amount_due which you would like:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    amount_due = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_amount_due(self, obj):
         amountgiven = obj.amountgiven_set.first()
         return amountgiven.amount_due
```

But again, as i already mentioned - amountgiven_set returns a queryset where you can have multiple objects.

In case you are sure you have only one for given contact, you can use `first()` as in my example to get it.

Comment: actually there is no `amount_due` column and yes there can be multiple records for `amount_given` for a single `contact`. I'm just summing up all the amounts given to a contact to return due amount. So, should I use `ModelManager` method instead of model method?

Comment: you can sum it up in the serializer. As in my example, you can use the serializerMethodField and do it in that method. But i like the approach in the other answer to this question. So look at that one.

Comment: used `ModelManager` to return the sum of all `amount_due` from model since there could be many records for a user and `amount_due` in model class is working on entity-based to calculate the due amount for a particular entity.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, you want the sum of all the amounts(please edit your question). so you should use annotate in your queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

def get_queryset(self):
    return Contact.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).annotate(amount_due=Sum('amountgiven_set__amount'))
```

(I recommend using modelManager for the queryset and the filtering instead of doing it here)

and add a field like this to your serializer:

```
amount_due = serializer.IntegerFiled()
```